# Consider 4 positive integers a,b,c,d having exactly 10^11 bits (considering the leading zeroes) in the binary representations

Tags: logic, binary

Consider 4 positive integers a,b,c,d  having exactly 10^11 bits (considering the leading zeroes) in the binary representations. Positions are numbered from 1 to 10^11. Every 3rd bit of a is equal to 1 (in other words bits number 3,6,9 and so-on), every 7th bit of b is equal to 1, every 4th bit of c is equal to 1, every 5th bit of d is equal to 1. The task is to determine the number of 1 bits in a ⊕ b ⊕ c ⊕ d, where ⊕ is bitwise XOR operation.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this question?

Answer (score 0):

The value of $(a \oplus b \oplus c \oplus d)_i$ depends on whether $i$ is divisible by $3,4,5,7$, and in particular, by $i \bmod 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 7$. In order to complete the calculation, you need to know, for each $j \in \{0,\ldots,3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 7 - 1\}$, how many indices $i \in \{1,\ldots,10^{11}\}$ satisfy $i \equiv j \pmod{3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 7}$.